# Deploy Custom ArcGIS API for JavaScript App (NOT a Web App Builder or Experience Builder App) to Portal for ArcGIS or ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online, arcgis-portal

I have read this question, https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-api-for-javascript-questions/deploying-a-custom-web-map-app-on-..., but the answers did not address the question. I have also searched ESRI docs and done some Google searches, but I have not found documentation on deploying custom JS API apps to a Portal server, and there are no forum posts with satisfactory answers.

So, my question is simple. Is it possible to deploy a custom ArcGIS API for JavaScript app (NOT a Web App Builder or Experience Builder app) to a Portal or ArcGIS Online? I have read here, https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/supported-items.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_6E84BE3C2FA542B9... that I can link an application to Portal, but I am assuming linking and hosting are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mixed up some concepts here. You cannot deploy apps to Portal for ArcGIS or ArcGIS Online. Only apps created inside the software are hosted there.

What you can do is deploying your app in a server (IIS, Tomcat, etc.) or in the cloud and then link it in the corresponding ArcGIS Software, so you can take advantage of the ArcGIS security options and so on.

Comment: Thanks Katah. I understand that I have to host an app on a server via IIS, Tomcat, etc. What I did not understand until yesterday is how to then get that app into Portal or ArcGIS Online. Now I understand that simply adding that app as a Portal or ArcGIS Online item is more than simply linking an app to Portal or ArcGIS Online, but I still do not understand how that will work in a case, for example, in which an app is hosted on an internal server but accessed via ArcGIS Online or Portal. That is what I am exploring.